# Add new cronjob to crontab using PHP

Tags: php, file, cron

I understand that people have asked this before but it is still unclear to me and their examples did not work. I want to be able to add a new cronjob to the crontab through a php script that I wrote. The php script concatenates a string which will represent the cronjob. For example:

> */1 * * * * php /example/path/sample.php

I want to add the line above to the end of my crontab. I understand you can edit a crontab using crontab -e, but I want to do this all through PHP. If the crontab is just a text file, I know how to write to it, but after searching online the crontab can be in several directories? I found examples where it is in /tmp and also in /var. If I want to append to a crontab and have that cronjob automatically run, where is the crontab located? I am using Debian linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

with crontab -e you write directly to crontab when you are in terminal... if you want to use a file to load to your crontab (and this is the only way if you want to do this in php) you must use crontab -l in terminal again to load the new file.

i dont know any way to manipulate terminal using php.
so create a file in php with the crontab commands, store it wherever you want and load it from the terminal

Comment: I'm trying to use the exec() function to run terminal commands. So as a test I tried exec("crontab -e"); just to see if it would take me to the crontab but it didn't do anything and I wasn't able to type any commands or even hit CTRL + C to exit